# How to focus to filtered list item using CursorAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView which use CursorAdapter for populating its rows.It's a sorted(by using query) list view having 2 TextViews, 2 Buttons, and an ImageView. Also the screen has a 'Search' box and A-Z alphabets horizontally just above the ListView.

I want to make tap on the A-Z alphabets will focus(scroll) the list item starting with that alphabet selected. Same for Search button also. I don't want to filter the list ,just  focus the existing item and scroll to that index.

How can i achieve such a functionality? Here is the code snippet what I used for getting cursor starting with selected alphabet.

```
 adapter.getFilter().filter(searchKey);
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

                            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                                Cursor cur = dbHelper
                                        .filterList(constraint
                                                .toString());

                                /*listView.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        listView.setSelection(cursor.getPosition());
                                    }
                                });*/

                                return cursor;
                            }

                        });
```

I don't know how to get the position of filtered cursor in the original cursor.

Comment: [`ListView.setSelection(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) and [`ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) were designed for this. You give it an index and it jumps/scrolls to that position in the list. In other words: if you want to jump to the first item starting with "H", you''ll have to figure out the position for it in your dataset. I suppose you can make an item's position either part of your query, or iterate through the cursor.

Comment: As a side note: consider using an [`AlphabetIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html) - it's a standard widget (thus Android ui pattern) and really what it's there for. :)

Comment: I tried AlphabetIndexer using http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/02/10/Implementing-a-ListView-with-AlphabetIndexer-and-CursorAdapter-on-Android.But it did not show while scrolling the ListView.